# How to politely tell recruiter that contacted me to not waste their time if they can’t offer visa sponsorship?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, visa, international

I'm a web developer, I was a match in a job search site for a position that I'm fit for and really interested in. The recruiter asked for my CV and phone number but it's not mentioned in their offer if they could sponsor a visa.

I'm not even sure if the recruiter knows I am not in his country. How I should tell him professionally that I'm interested but need a visa from them to work there?

Comment: Is the fact you need visa sponsorship front and centre on your CV?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Right after my name it says my nationality and my current location (same as nationality) but i didn't send it yet, because he asked for my phone and that tells me that he believes i'm there, so it's pointless to give him my foreign phone number

Comment: @RubenGonzalez, it's up to them to decide whether it's pointless to continue, so just go ahead — a phone call before they have seen your CV is usually not about a particular position yet, but more of a verification that you are sufficiently serious that they should actually look at the CV. I'd point out during the call that you'd need a visa to work in a different country, but take great care not to present it as a problem (last but not least because it's not *your* problem, but theirs, and they need to come to their own conclusion if it's worth it).

Comment: The thing about recruiters is: they don't work for the company, but for themselves. They get a (really) nice bonus when a contract is made, so they have a strong interest in placing one of their candidates. This means they create a list of suitable people, and then do whatever they can to get one of them hired. So the recruiter will decide whether it is worth proceeding, and either give you a negative result very quickly, or (usually after a few weeks) contact you about interviewing with the company, at which point they will already have cleared most of the obstacles out of the way.

Comment: As @SimonRichter mentioned, recruiters (usually) don't work direct for companies, so it is very probably not even he who can actually decide over this. But since he is a recruiter he should usually be able to answer basic questions about the offer, including if it can involve a VISA sponsorship.

Comment: Related: [Where should I say that I need sponsorship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10787)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How I should tell him professionally that I'm interested but need a
>   visa from them to work there?

Just say that.

"Hi (recruiter), that sounds interesting! I'm not sure if you noticed but I'm based in (city, country). Does the role offer visa sponsorship? If so please contact me at (contact information). I've also attached my CV."

Comment: Make sure to include your CV and phone number with this response.